# Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly. Python Error

Tags: python, string, integer

This is my code trying to convert a sentence to camel case whenever a '-' or '_' appears.

```
def to_camel_case(text):
    for i in text:   
        if text[0].isupper():
            text[0] = text[0].upper()
        elif i == '_' or i == '-':
            text[i] = text[i].upper()
    return text
```

On executing the code it says the mentioned error. I know the error is somewhere in the line `text[i] = text[i].upper()` but I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input `text` on which it is failing?

Comment: It failed on `"hello_world"` when I ran it

Comment: Any String inputted as such: 'to_camel_case' or 'to-camel-case'.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @yatu I tried changing the 'i' to 'i+1' in the line 'text[i] = text[i].upper()'. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @yatu It's not trying to convert them that throws the error, it's trying to use them as list indices. Iterating over `range(len(text))` rather than over `text` should help, though that just means you get a string assignment error instead.

Comment: @Jay like 'to_camel_case("hey_there")' returns 'heyThere'

Comment: @yatu It's not an error to "convert" `_` or `_` to upper case; you just get the same character back.

Comment: `i` is a character, not an index; strings are immutable; and you seem to be missing a lot of negation (e.g., if a character is uppercase, you try to uppercase it.) You need to rethink your whole approach.

Comment: I don't understand the first ```if```. You are always checking if the first character in ```text``` is of uppercase. If it is, you convert to uppercase character? In my opinion this ```if``` doesn't change anything (except for the fact, that you won't branch to ```else```).

Comment: @chepner alright, thanks for that. My bad I guess. Just starting out sooo.

Comment: @Melon What i really need to do is, if the first character of my string is in uppercase, only then I've gotta capitalize it. If it isn't, I leave that character and camel case on the other words of the string.

Comment: Okay, you know that ```string``` in Python is immutable? ```text[0] = text[0].upper()``` will not work. Unless ```text``` is a ```list``` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use `string.title` having replaced both `-` or `_` to spaces with `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = "hello_world"

re.sub('_|-',' ',s).title()
# 'Hello World'
```

Comment: Thanks. Need to work on Regular Expressions though. :s

Comment: Yes is that an inconvenient for you? I used it for commodity as it allows for replacing multiple substrings at once

Comment: No it is fine. I haven't really used regular expressions before so I'm working out how it goes. Thanks for the different approach though!

Comment: `re.sub` is essentially the regex version of `string.replace`. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

A Non-Regex / Crude-Logic(:D) version:

```
def to_camel_case(text):
    pos_list = [x+1 for x,c in enumerate(text) if ((c == '_' or c == '-') and (x!=len(text)))]

    new_text_list = []
    for i, c in enumerate(text):
        if (c == '-' or c == '_'):
            continue
        if i in pos_list:
            new_text_list.append(c.upper())
        else:
            new_text_list.append(c)

    return "".join(x for x in new_text_list)



print to_camel_case("hey_there")
print to_camel_case("-In_this_World_")
print to_camel_case("hello_world")
```

**Output:**

```
heyThere
InThisWorld
helloWorld
```

Comment: Sweet. Thanks! What does this line ' pos_list = [x+1 for x,c in enumerate(text) if ((c == '_' or c == '-') and (x!=len(text)))]' do if I may ask.

Comment: This line calculates the position of the characters next to '-' or '_', so that only those letters can be converted to upper case later on.